# How do you disable <script> elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to disable `<script>` tags. Here's my code, but it doesn't work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('script').disabled = true;
```

Comment: There is no disabled attribute for the script tag.

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "disable script tags"? Disable how and why? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @covanova Just out of curiosity, how would you apply a disabled attribute to a CSS stylesheet?

Comment: Related: [Use JavaScript to prevent a later `<script>` tag from being evaluated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726362/use-javascript-to-prevent-a-later-script-tag-from-being-evaluated) Btw, `getElementsByTagName` returns a **`NodeList`**. If you wanted to assign properties to elements, you'd have to iterate over the list first. Which attributes are supported by the `script` can be found in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1).

Comment: @FelixKling : I will keep that in mind, Sir. I'm a JS noob. I still haven't really got the hang of it. Thanks for the tip! +1 for the specs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can't be done... A script tag evaluates as soon as the DOM renderer renders it, so getting a handle on it after wards won't do much.

Answer (score 17):

In fact, it is possible to disable execution by changing "type" attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("I will alert you");
</script>

<script type="application/json">
    alert("And I will keep silent");
</script>

<script>
    alert("I will alert too");
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r6c0x0sc/

Comment: But if it's executed it won't be executed again anyway. So no need to disable it in this case. If it has added an event listener, or you did setInterval() in it - surely those won't be disabled even if you delete <script> tag from DOM, such needs to be handled differently. I just mean it's possible to add a non-executable script into DOM.

Comment: This seems quite useful for user generated or embedded HTML that is rendered and displayed after the main page load.

Answer (score 1):

**You can** disable a script element.  There are a couple of ways:

You can specify a **different script type** as other have listed.  Heres the one that worked for me:

```
//loop through all script tags on page
$('script').each(function(){
    var scripthtml = $(this).html();
    $(this).replaceWith('<script type="text/gzip">' + scripthtml + '</script>');
});
```

All of the official script types can all be found here:  [iana.org](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text)

The second way is just a **simple if statement**:

```
//loop through all script tags on page
$('script').each(function(){
    var scripthtml = $(this).html();
    $(this).replaceWith('<script>if (1==0){' + scripthtml + '}</script>');
});
```

The if statement will always be false, so anything inside the script tag won't execute.  However all of your functions() inside the script tag will all be valid.

Heres the **javascript equivalent** of replaceWith:

```
//get script and html
var yourscripttag = document.getElementById('yourscripttagID');
var scripthtml = 'if (1==0){' + yourscripttag.innerHTML + '}';
//remove script
yourscripttag.remove();
//create new script element
var newscript=document.createElement('script');
newscript.type='text/javascript';
//insert html in new script tag
newscript.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scripthtml));
//insert new script tag into head
document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(newscript);
```

Comment: May God bless you for taking the time to write `text/gzip`. This was the answer for me

Answer (score 1):

You can hack it.  Use another script to do a....

```
node.parentNode.replaceChild(
  document.createComment(node.outerHTML.slice(1,-1)
    .replace(/--/g, '\\-\\-')), node);
```

Where node is your script node/element.  The replacing of double dashes is to prevent the browser complaining about an uncompliant comment tag.

Then if you want to enable it just do the reverse comment.replace and enclose with < and >.  But you probably need to keep track of the modified script node, because after it becomes a comment it is less query-able.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are getting some HTML code from the Database and add it to the page.
If so, You can write a Server Side function that will add a HTML Notes around the scripts using a simple Regex and after that the user saving the changes you will need to remove the notes.

You can do it also in Javascript if you have the HTML string that you like to add before you add it to the Dom.

Answer (score -1):

Removing all the events on DOM nodes will prevent most of the JavaScript from executing (here for `document`):

```
for (key in getEventListeners(document)) {
  getEventListeners(document)[key].forEach(function(c) {
    c.remove()
  })   
}
```