# PhantomJS create page from string

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

Is it possible to create a page from a string?

example:

```
html = '<html><body>blah blah blah</body></html>'

page.open(html, function(status) {
  // do something
});
```

I have already tried the above with no luck....

Also, I think it's worth mentioning that I'm using nodejs with phantomjs-node(https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the phantomjs [API](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface), page.open requires a URL as the first argument, not an HTML string. This is why the what you tried does not work.

However, one way that you might be able to achieve the effect of creating a page from a string is to host an empty "skeleton page," somewhere with a URL (could be localhost), and then include Javascript (using includeJs) into the empty page. The Javascript that you include into the blank page can use `document.write("<p>blah blah blah</p>")` to dynamically add content to the webpage.

I've ever done this, but AFAIK this should work.

Sample skeleton page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I figured as much... I saw something where someone was loading in local files and pushing them into an array then "opening" them with Phantom. I thought they were actually loading in the html content but after looking again I realized it was just the filename! I believe the above should work for me just fine.... thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 122):

It's very simple, take a look at the [colorwheel.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/colorwheel.js) example.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.content = '<html><body><p>Hello world</p></body></html>';
```

That's all! Then you can manipulate the page, e.g. render it as an image.

Comment: I'm super late on this but... this only works when using the cli version of phantom. Not possible with the plugin I'm using... again.

Comment: @mike, this isn't node.js code, this is the phantom script and can be used with the many npm phantom modules I've seen.

Comment: Will this also render javascript embedded in the html string? like '<html><script>js that modifies the page here...</script><script src='someotherpagemodifyingcode.js'></script>..blahblah</html>'

Comment: @sjdirect For that you're probably better off doing `page.injectJs("someotherpagemodifyingcode.js");`

Answer (score 19):

**To do this you need to set the page content to your string.**

```
phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
      page.set('viewportSize', {width:1440,height:900})

      //like this
      page.set('content', html);

      page.render(path_to_pdf, function() { 
        //now pdf is written to disk.
        ph.exit();
      });
  });
});
```

you need to use `page.set()` to set the html content.

as per https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#functionality-details

> Properties can't be get/set directly.
>   Instead use **page.get('version', callback)** or page.set('viewportSize', {width:640,height:480}), etc.
>
> Nested objects can be accessed by including dots in keys, such as
>   **page.set('settings.loadImages', false)**

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to mention I recently had a similar need and discovered that I could pass file:// style references as an URL param, so I dumped my HTML string into a local file then passed the full path to my capture script (django_screamshot) which basically uses casperjs and phantomjs + a capture.js script.

Anyway it just works and its reasonably fast..

Answer (score 2):

I got the following to work in PhantomJS version 2.0.0. Whereas before, I was using page.open() to open a page from the filesystem and set a callback:

```
page.open("bench.html", pageLoadCallback);
```

Now, I accomplish the same thing from a string variable with the HTML page. The `page.setContent()` method requires a URL as the second argument, and this uses `fs.absolute()` to construct a *file://* URL.

```
page.onLoadFinished = pageLoadCallback;
page.setContent(bench_str, "file://" + fs.absolute(".") + "/bench.html");
```