# Need to save pandas correlation Highlighted table (cmap Matplotlib) as png image

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-science

Used this code to genrate corelation table:

```
df1.drop(['BC DataPlus', 'AC Glossary'], axis=1).corr(method='pearson').style.format("{:.2}").background_gradient(cmap=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm'), axis=1)
```

This is the table generated:
[image: Correlation Table]

I cant find any way to save this table as image. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a figure handle being returned somewhere?

Comment: Perhaps if you were to break up the giant chain of calls into a couple of lines?

Comment: Related, not 100% dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35634238/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist no figure handle is returned and thats why I am unable to save as image

Comment: Then what are you calling `style` on?

Comment: One of the objects in that chain has a figure handle in it. Read the API docs carefully and you'll find it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I strongly doubt that. There is no matplotlib figure involved here at all (unless you know something that many others don't, in which case it would be good to provide an answer here).

Comment: The main point here is that the table has a HTML representation, but no png representation (i.e you cannot do `IPython.display.display_png(table)`) hence you need to use any of the numerous workarounds listed in the link above or in links in that link. Depending on how often you need to do that, just doing a screenshot and saving that as png might be the fastest option.

Comment: Guys I still haven't reached any solution, So can you please help me out. Thank you so much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question you pose is difficult to answer if taken literally.
The difficulty stems from the fact that `df.style.render()` generates HTML which is then sent to a browser to be rendered as an image. The result may not be exactly the same across all browsers either.

Python is not directly involved in the generation of the image. So there is no
straight-forward Python-based solution.

Nevertheless, the issue of how to convert HTML to png
[was raised](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14023) on the pandas developers'
github page and the suggested
answer was to [use `phantomjs`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067021/190597).  Other ways (that I haven't tested) might be to use
[`webkit2png`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5634130/190597) or
[GrabzIt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291677/190597).

We could avoid much of this difficulty, however, if we loosen the interpretation of the question. Instead of trying to produce the exact image generated by `df.style` (for a particular browser),
we could generate a *similar* image very easily using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((6, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(df.corr(method='pearson'), annot=True, fmt='.4f', 
            cmap=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm'), cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation="horizontal")
plt.savefig('result.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

[image]

---

If you don't want to add the seaborn dependency, you could [use matplotlib directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35905393/190597) though it takes a few more lines of code:

```
import colorsys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((6, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
corr = df.corr(method='pearson')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = corr.values
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm'), 
                    vmin=np.nanmin(data), vmax=np.nanmax(data))
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.invert_yaxis()
row_labels = corr.index
column_labels = corr.columns
ax.set_xticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)

def _annotate_heatmap(ax, mesh):
    """
    **Taken from seaborn/matrix.py**
    Add textual labels with the value in each cell.
    """
    mesh.update_scalarmappable()
    xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(ax.get_xticks(), ax.get_yticks())
    for x, y, val, color in zip(xpos.flat, ypos.flat,
                                mesh.get_array(), mesh.get_facecolors()):
        if val is not np.ma.masked:
            _, l, _ = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*color[:3])
            text_color = ".15" if l > .5 else "w"
            val = ("{:.3f}").format(val)
            text_kwargs = dict(color=text_color, ha="center", va="center")
            # text_kwargs.update(self.annot_kws)
            ax.text(x, y, val, **text_kwargs)

_annotate_heatmap(ax, heatmap)
plt.savefig('result.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```