# PhantomJS how to render javascript in html string

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to get PhantomJS to take an html string and then have it render the full page as a browser would (including execution of any javascript in the page source). I need the resulting html result as a string. I have seen examples of page.open which is of no use since I already have the page source in my database.

Do I need to use page.open to trigger the javascript rendering engine in PhantomJS? Is there anyway to do this all in memory (ie.. without page.open making a request or reading/writing html source from/to disk?

I have seen a similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744089/phantomjs-create-page-from-string) but it doesn't quite solve my issue. After running the code below, nothing I do seems to render the javascript in the html source string.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.setContent('raw html and javascript in this string', 'http://whatever.com');
//everything i've tried from here on doesn't execute the javascript in the string
```

--------------Update---------------

Tried the following based on the suggestion below but this still does not work. Just returns the raw source that I supplied with no javascript rendered.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true;
page.settings.webSecurityEnabled = false;
page.onLoadFinished = function(){
    var resultingHtml = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    });
    console.log(resultingHtml);
    //console.log(page.content); // this didn't work either
    phantom.exit();
};
page.url = input.Url;
page.content = input.RawHtml;
//page.setContent(input.RawHtml, input.Url); //this didn't work either
```

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setTimeout made it work even though I'm not excited to wait a set amount of time for each page. The waitFor approach that is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747643/does-phantom-js-capture-all-ajax) doesn't work since I have no idea what elements each page might have.

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.setContent(input.RawHtml, input.Url);
window.setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
}, input.WaitToRenderTimeInMilliseconds);
```

Comment: I'll likely try something like checkin $.active in the future to see if the page has any pending ajax requests. Then i could avoid doing a setTimeout.

Comment: You can also use some of the suggestions from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11340038/1816580) to wait for a full page load.

Answer (score 3):

The following works

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(){
    console.log(page.content); // rendered content
};
page.content = "your source html string";
```

But you have to keep in mind that if you set the page from a string, the domain will be about:blank. So if the html loads resources from other domains, then you should run PhantomJS with the `--web-security=false --local-to-remote-url-access=true` commandline options:

```
phantomjs --web-security=false --local-to-remote-url-access=true script.js
```

Additionally, you may need to wait for the completion of the JavaScript execution which might be not be finished when PhantomJS thought it finished. Use either `setTimeout()` to wait a static amount of time or [`waitFor()`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to wait for a specific condition on a page. More robust ways to wait for a full page are given in this question: [phantomjs not waiting for “full” page load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11340038/1816580)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my question above with code trying what you are suggesting. This still does not appear to solve my problem. Just returns the raw source that I supplied it with nothing rendered.

Comment: You haven't said anything about what your page is doing, so I provided a general answer. I also extended it a little now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you want, but using PhantomJsCloud.com you can do it easily, Here's an example:  [http://api.phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request={url:%22http://example.com%22,content:%22%3Ch1%3ENew%20Content!%3C/h1%3E%22,renderType:%22png%22,scripts:{domReady:[%22var%20hiDiv=document.createElement%28%27div%27%29;hiDiv.innerHTML=%27Hello%20World!%27;document.body.appendChild%28hiDiv%29;window._pjscMeta.scriptOutput={Goodbye:%27World%27};%22]},outputAsJson:false}](http://api.phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request=%7Burl:%22http://example.com%22,content:%22%3Ch1%3ENew%20Content!%3C/h1%3E%22,renderType:%22png%22,scripts:%7BdomReady:[%22var%20hiDiv=document.createElement%28%27div%27%29;hiDiv.innerHTML=%27Hello%20World!%27;document.body.appendChild%28hiDiv%29;window._pjscMeta.scriptOutput=%7BGoodbye:%27World%27%7D;%22]%7D,outputAsJson:false%7D)  The "New Content!"  is the content that replaces the original content, and the "Hello World!" is placed in the page by a script.

If you want to do this via normal PhantomJs, you'll need to use the injectJs or includeJs functions, after the page content is loaded.

Comment: oh and disclosure, I wrote PhantomJsCloud