# how to improve the quality of a `html2canvas` screen capture?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I have used the following `html2canvas` code to take screenshots and download it.

**html button creation**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin:0px 0px -10px 970px; padding:2px 4px 1px 4px" onclick="genScreenshot()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button>
<a id="test"></a>
<div id="box1"></div>
```

**function definition**

```
<script type="text/javascript">                         
function genScreenshot() {
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
  $('#box1').html("");

  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || 
                navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) 
       {
    var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,'Test file.png');
       }
  else {
    $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    $('#test').attr('download','screenshot.png');
    $('#test')[0].click();
       }
                                }
                              });
                          }  
</script>
```

But the quality of the downloaded screenshot is not that good. How can improve its quality?

Comment: I suggest to use `phantomJS` http://phantomjs.org/  to capture a screenshot , it's more accurate and advanced

Comment: Read my question correctly, I dont wanna give the `url` directly which is required in `phantomjs`. Is there a way to work with `phantomjs` without entering the `url` for the screenshot to be taken?

Comment: Yes , you can by providing full html text  , check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744089/phantomjs-create-page-from-string

Comment: They are not talking about screen captures there!

Comment: after setting `content` you can call `page.render`

Comment: zoom your control then take a screenshot of it

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
var $wrapper = $("#yourDiv");
setSize($wrapper, "2000px", "20pt");

html2canvas($wrapper, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        a.download = 'filename.jpg';
        a.click();

        setSize($wrapper, "1000px", "10pt");
    }
});

function setSize(dv, width, fontsize) {
    dv[0].style.width = width;
    dv[0].style.fontSize = fontsize;
}
```

This resizes the div and font to bigger size and then shrinks back afterwards.